# Kibana 4 : Url not formatted properly

Tags: url, kibana-4, elasticsearch-2.0

I have a field in my index like

```
path: /abc/nvb/jklk.txt
```

I autoindex it as string and it is displayed as above. Now, i want to convert it to a url. So in the index settings in Kibana, i apply set this field as a Url and apply

Url Template

```
hostname:portNumber#{{value}}
```

Label template

```
{{value}}
```

now this field appears as a link in my discover view. But when i click on it, it navigates to

```
hostName:portNumber#%2Fabc%2Fnvb%2Fjklk.txt
```

why did all of my `/`s get replaced by `%2F` ? Note that, i was expecting the link to navigate to

```
hostName:portNumber#/abc/nvb/jklk.txt
```

which is indeed a valid url

I have tried putting the value as

```
path: //abc//nvb//jklk.txt
```

and even

```
path: \/abc\/nvb\/jklk.txt
```

but the result is the same. The slashes always get encoded. Is there a way to solve this? Will I have to modify my mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be

Url Template

```
hostname:portNumber#{{rawValue}}
```